# How to Test the SMTP settings from Peopelsoft Application Server?

Tags: peoplesoft

I configured the SMTP settings in Application Server and Process Scheduler Server to send the reports over email. I ran a sample reports to test it in Process Scheduler. This works fine. How can I test **SMTP settings** in **application server** ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom component and page, put a single button on the page.

FieldChange PeopleCode:

```
Local string &MAIL_CC, &MAIL_TO, &MAIL_BCC, &MAIL_SUBJECT, &MAIL_TITLES, &MAIL_TEXT, &MAIL_FILES, &MAIL_FROM, &REPLYTO, &SENDER;
Local number &MAIL_FLAGS;

&MAIL_FLAGS = 0;
&MAIL_TO = "email-address-message-going-to";
&MAIL_CC = "";
&MAIL_BCC = "";
&MAIL_SUBJECT = "Test email"; 
&MAIL_TEXT = "Sending an email from PeopleCode.";
&MAIL_FILES = "";
&MAIL_TITLES = "";
&MAIL_FROM = "email-address-message-is-from";
&MAIL_SEP = ";";
&CONTTYPE = "";
&REPLYTO = "";
&SENDER = ""; 

&RET = SendMail(&MAIL_FLAGS, &MAIL_TO, &MAIL_CC, &MAIL_BCC, &MAIL_SUBJECT, &MAIL_TEXT, &MAIL_FILES, &MAIL_TITLES, &MAIL_FROM, &MAIL_SEP, &CONTTYPE, &REPLYTO, &SENDER); 

If &RET <> 0 Then
 MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, "Return code from SendMail= " | &RET);
 /*Do error processing here*/ 
End-If;
```

You could add fields to the page for each &MAIL_ variable if you want a more robust test tool, otherwise just hardcode it.